# How to convert Unix Epoch Timestamp to Erlang timestamp format?

Tags: erlang, unix-timestamp, datetime-conversion

I'm trying to add a few extra features to my ejabberd `mod_muc_room`, but `jlib:now_to_utc_string` doesn't seem to accept Unix timestamps and requires them to be in Erlang's built-in format. Trying to use "`1519633372486003`" instead of "`{1519,633372,486003}`" makes `mod_muc_room` crash.

I found at least several ways to convert an Erlang timestamp into a Unix timestamp, but I can't find a way to make a reverse conversion.

Is there a way to do that without converting integer to binary and binary to tuple before concatenating the numbers together and converting them back into numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `div` and `rem` to extract the three values:

```
1> M = 1000000.
1000000
2> T = 1519633372486003.
1519633372486003
3> {T div M div M, T div M rem M, T rem M}.
{1519,633372,486003}
```

Comment: @Shrenostal if this answer solved your problem, you can "accept" it by clicking the check mark on the side. That gives some extra points to both you and the answerer :)